# Cisco Packet Tracer - script copying

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, cisco-commands, packet-tracer

I have to define a big amount of VLANs in a rather big amount of switches using Cisco packet tracer software. I was wondering whether there is a way to copy-paste all those commands from one switch to the others, or if it exists any kind of scripting available for that.

Comment: Cannot you use VTP?

Comment: I can, but anyway, is there a way to copy some commands and execute them in block in another device?

Comment: Can't you just highlight with the mouse, copy (<CTRL>-C), and paste (<CRTL>-V)?

Comment: I routinely take entire config files, edit them to change some names and IP addresses, and then apply them to new switches. That's one of the great benefits of a CLI and the way IOS configuration files work.

Comment: `copy tftp running-config` -- that's doesn't *replace* the running config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have to copy-paste big configurations I use a text editor. I put there all the reusable rows in this manner:

```
enable
!
configure terminal
!
vlan 10
!
name VLAN10
!
vlan 20
!
name VLAN20
!
exit
!
exit
```

Please notice the exclamation mark ( "!" ) that I put below each row, it makes the text reusable! And I don't put the "Switch>" part, just copy the text and paste it in the CLI. It doesn't look very automated, but... it's just Packet Tracer. :)